# Java self-reflection

Tags: java, reflection

It's rather strange, but I want to call self method.

This is my abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractMapper {
    public AbstractMapper(Map<String, String> map) {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field: fields) {
            if (field.getAnnotation(Column.class) != null) {
                String fName = field.getName();
                String rsName = field.getAnnotation(Column.class).name();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("set")
                        .append(Character.toUpperCase(fName.charAt(0)))
                        .append(fName.substring(1));
                String mName = sb.toString();

//              this.invoke(mName, map.get(fName)); <-- What should I put this here?
            }
        }
    }
    public Result getCalculatedValues() {
        return xxxx;
    }
}
```

And this is my class

```
public class NewMachine extends AbstractMapper{
    @column(name = machine)
    private String machine;

    @column(name = temperature)
    private Double temperature;

    // normal get/set methods

 }
```

Now, my goal is that AbstractMapper constructor iterates through all fields with columns, and invoke all of its respective setters.

in this case, I can pass something like

```
Map<String, String> map = SomeClass.SomeMethod();
NewMachine m = new NewMachine(map);
Result r = m.getCalculatedValues();
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Ah.. nothing special.. just experimenting with reflection. Just want see how to code or how it works, and how fast it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `getClass().getMethod( mName, field.getType() ).invoke(this, map.get(fName) )` (and handle any possible exceptions ofc).

Additionally keep the JavaDoc on `getDeclaredFields()` in mind:

> Returns an array of {@code Field} objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but *excludes inherited fields*.

If you have a hierarchy you'd have to get the fields of the super classes as well.